# Is it safe to put an std::array<POD, N> in a union?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stl

I have a union declared like that:

```
union
{
    int all[4];
    struct
    {
        int a, b, c, d;
    };
};
```

The point of the `all` array is simply to make iteration over the 4 fields simpler.

To make it even simpler, I'd like to replace it with an `std::array<int, 4>`. Would that expose me to [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, it's important to note that merely having two objects of different types in a union is *never* undefined. What's undefined is to write to one and read from another, with one exception:

> `[C++11: 9.5/1]:` *[ Note:* One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence (9.2), and if an object of this standard-layout union type contains one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of standard-layout struct members; see 9.2. —*end note ] [..]*

Now, although it's not written out specifically anywhere that `std::array` fits this rule, the fact that it's an aggregate with only element members seems enough of a guarantee:

> `[C++11: 23.3.2.1/2]:` An array is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the syntax:
>
> `array<T, N> a = {` *initializer-list* `};`
>
> where *initializer-list* is a comma-separated list of up to `N` elements whose types are convertible to `T`.

So, it's safe not only to have the union exist in the first place, but also to read and write to either member at will.

Therefore, my conclusion is: **yes; it is safe**.

Comment: To reduce confusion, I've changed the title to "is it *safe* to ...", so I edited the "no; it is safe" into "yes; it is safe".

Comment: Maybe it's _not_ enough. Turns out layout-compatibility is extremely restrictive. If nothing else, actually, four `int`s is not a standard-layout struct.

Comment: Wait, `struct { int a,b,c,d; }` is not standard layout?  Them's fighting words.

Comment: I don't think it's guaranteed that `std::array` is a standard-layout class, and I'm not sure if it's guaranteed that struct with four `int` data members is layout-compatible to a raw array.

Comment: @Yakk: I believe the question is whether `int a,b,c,d` _not in a `struct`_ are layout-compatible with the `struct` you described. That's a whole new thing.

Comment: For what it's worth, [according to g++](http://ideone.com/7WFcu3), the union itself is standard-layout, which transitively means that it considers that both `std::array<int, N>` and the "inline struct" are. If g++'s `is_standard_layout` conforms to the standard, then this construct should be safe.