# Array of objects not initialized to 0

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm trying to initialize an array of objects with 0 like this (simplified code of a more complex project) :

```
#include <iostream>

struct Vector {
    float s[4];
    Vector() {}
    static Vector zero() {
        Vector v;
        v.s[0] = 0;
        v.s[1] = 0;
        v.s[2] = 0;
        v.s[3] = 0;
        return v;
    }
};

struct Test {
    Vector v[4] = { Vector::zero() };
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Test t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%f %f %f %f\n", t.v[i].s[0], t.v[i].s[1], t.v[i].s[2], t.v[i].s[3]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code should print all 0, but sometimes it prints different values. Looks like only the first element of the array is initialized. But if I write float x[4] = { 0 }, then all elements of the array x are initialized with 0. What is the difference and where in the C++ standard can I read about this behavior?

Comment: make s global and it's elements will be initialised to 0

Comment: @Cornstalks thanks, I fixed it, but doesn't change the underlying problem.

Comment: @QuentinUK thanks, I know this, but I can't do this :-)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why did you ask for a reference to the standard if you're happy with an answer that doesn't mention the standard?

Comment: I'd be happier if it were std::array<float,4> which the instructor should be forcing you to use, not preventing, IMHO.

Comment: @KennyOstrom even if OP where to use std::array, he would still need to do something like std::array<float,4> arr{} to ensure initialization, or am I wrong?

Comment: @melpomene I think the cppreference.com article was close enough, I'm not a language lawyer and reading the standard is not fun anyway :-) and the answer provided a good solution for my problem

Comment: You might want to consider writing `Vector()=default;`: that causes default initialization to be trivial (*i.e.*, fast) but gets you zero-initialization from `{}` and the like.

Comment: @KennyOstrom, thanks for the feedback, sorry I didn't see your answer. I added your point to mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might want to look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

With

```
Vector v[4] = { Vector::zero() };
```

You initialize the first element, the other 3 are initialized with calls to the default ctor that does not initialize the array (the body of your default ctor is empty).

Substitute  at the beginning the array declaration with

```
float s[4]{};
```

This will value-initialize the array, zeroing it. Then you can remove everything else.

To read the relationship between value-initialization and zero-initialization, please refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

Furthermore, as noted by user Kenny Ostrom in the comments, you might want to consider using `std::array`, keeping in mind that you will need still to value-initialize it, see [Default initialization of std::array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295302/default-initialization-of-stdarray) .
Lastly, as noted in the comments access to x[4] is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the x[4] access in my original posting. I don't know if I can change it to std::array, it is within an union and has some alignment requirements. The original code where the problem happened is here:
https://github.com/VCVRack/Fundamental/blob/01fe49d256df8d10c901e1cbad693bb5ec50f04a/src/ADSR.cpp#L41
And this is the problematic line without initialization, which I now suggested to change to your solution:
https://github.com/VCVRack/Rack/blob/d89034b01c0dc13ecc2a374d82610334d557f8cc/include/simd/vector.hpp#L40
(the same file has a typedef for float_4)

Comment: IMHO the substitution should be fine, but I am not sure, I am not a fan of unions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763002/is-it-safe-to-put-an-stdarraypod-n-in-a-union. You might want to consider using a variant (std or boost) instead of a plain union.

Comment: @FrankBuss again, not an expert on unions here, but I am afraid that my solution might not be suitable for your particular use-case, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812555/how-to-zero-initialize-an-union

Comment: The developer has zeroed it now in the constructor:
https://github.com/VCVRack/Rack/commit/01d60a0bb14e25486ff8e644a096b53dcf154183
Should be safe. The only problem is that it assumes sizeof(float)==4, but might work on all supported platforms.

Comment: Great! You can consider adding a static_asset(sizeof(float) == 4, "ERROR") to the code so that if the size is not 4 it won't compile and you know it compile-time instead of runtime. Regards

Comment: He changed it again so that it behaves now like a simple type. Now the Vector class has this constructor:
Vector() = default;
So this works now as expected:
Vector v[4] = { 0 };
I still don't like it, I think it is a design flaw of C++ that it is possible to use uninitialized values. I understand that it needs some more instructions and time, but shouldn't matter much these days.